# How to propagate a JSF locale to other layers in the application

Tags: java, jsf, locale

In Java Server Faces, we normally get the locale of the current request with the `UIViewRoot.getLocale()` method, which would normally return the locale set in the browser. In a layered application, how can I read the same locale in other layers, where there's no access to the JSF objects? It seems that `Locale.getDefault()` is not suitable, because it returns a JVM-wide default locale. I need the context locale, set only by the current request from the browser. I assume it needs to have some kind of thread-affinity, like with .NET's `Thread.CurrentCulture` property.

Comment: What exactly do you need it for? Have you considered just passing it through as an argument?

Comment: This shouldn't be an argument, it's a kind of contextual information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it as an argument to methods that need it. This is, I think, the best approach.

```
public void businessMethod(String someArg, int otherArg, Locale locale) {
   ..
}
```

It however requires modifying your method signatures. You can implement something like in .NET via:

```
public final class LocaleProvider {
    private static ThreadLoca<Locale> currentLocale;
    //static setters and getters for the threadLocal
}
```

But this is essentially what `FacesContext.get....getLocale()` is doing. So except for getting rid of the dependencies on JSF in your service layer, you are not doing much more.

That said, current `Locale` should rarely be needed in the business operations. Two examples I can think of:

- sending emails (the appropriate template should be chosen)
- generating documents (like pdf) in the appropriate language

So, think twice before you include a locale dependency in your business-logic.

Comment: Interesting roll-your-own solution. But I was looking more for an official, in-the-framework, way of doing this, like in .NET. If it doesn't exist, I'll probably go with your idea.

Answer (score 3):

Not really the answer you probably expect, but in a layered design the answer should be: **you don't.**

Only the presentation layer is supposed to do data formatting according to the locale.

The business layer and the data layer should hold and manipulate data in locale-independent fashion.

Comment: in rare cases it needs the locale (see my answer)

Comment: I would argue that these cases that have to do with customer communication are better supported if you introduce a customer entity that has all the preference for the customer, such as default language, email address, etc. Then you pass the customer entity along. Most of the time, I don't want the communication in french while my browser is in english :) But I see your point though.

Comment: The locale can also be used for, e.g., getting the product names in the user's language from the data access layer. Isn't this a valid point for accessing the locale of the user from lower layers?

Comment: I agree that it's maybe not that black and white. How to deal with end-to-end internationalization of web application is an interesting question on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Locale is oriented only for web layer; service layer and dao layer should use a custom Language domain object. For templates, emails, etc convert Locale into Language or use a default language.

Think this: what happens if I call a web service which will call a service that uses locale? Locale will be null!